# Jordan form step by step general algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, jordan-normal-form

So I am trying to compile a summary of the procedure one should follow to find the Jordan basis and the Jordan form of a matrix, and I am on the lookout for free resources online where the algorithm to be followed is clearly explained in an amenable way.

I have found some interesting youtube videos but what I am on the lookout for is a written thing.

Alternatively, if you are so kind as to flesh out the procedure I would be happy to accept that as an answer.

Comment: Abstract Algebra, 3rd Edition by Dummit and. Foote, http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~spl/old_courses/304_fall_2008/handouts/jordan.pdf and algorithm: http://math.rice.edu/~friedl/math355_fall04/Jordan.pdf

Comment: I suppose you could also look at: https://math.berkeley.edu/~wilken/papers/Achain.pdf and http://math.cts.nthu.edu.tw/Mathematics/RANMEP%20Slides/Zhonggang%20Zeng.pdf

Comment: See also [Jordan Canonical Form: Theory and Practice](http://www.morganclaypool.com/doi/abs/10.2200/S00218ED1V01Y200908MAS006)

Comment: Neither of the links above works for me ... can somebody fix them please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Find all the eigenvalues of $T$.
- For each eigenvalue $\lambda$:
- Let $N = T-\lambda I$.
- Compute $N^2, N^3, \dots, N^n$.
- Find the generalized eigenspace $G=G(\lambda,T)$ of solutions $u$ to $N^n u = 0$.
- Find a temporary basis for $G$.
- Let $U_0 = G$, $U_n = \{0\}$ and $B_n = \emptyset$.
- For $k=n-1,\dots,1,0$:

  - Find $U_k = $range$ (N_{|_G})^k$ by applying $N^k$ to the temporary basis of $G$.
  - From the previous step we have a Jordan basis $B_{k+1}$ to $T_{|_{U_{k+1}}}$ given by
    $N^{d_1}v_1,\dots,N^2 v_1, N v_1, v_1, \dots, N^{d_m}v_m,\dots,N^2 v_m, N v_m, v_m$, with the property that $N^{d_j+1} v_j = 0$ for all $j$.
  - For $j=1,\dots,m$, find one $u_j$ such that $N u_j = v_j$.
  - Let $\tilde B_k = N^{d_1}v_1,\dots,N^2 v_1, N v_1, v_1, u_1 \dots, N^{d_m}v_m,\dots,N^2 v_m, N v_m, v_m, u_m$. Then $\tilde B_k$ is a Jordan basis for $T$ restricted to its span.
  - Find $A_k$ such that $\tilde B_k \cup A_k$ is a basis for $U_k$.
  - For each $w\in A_k$:

    - Find $x \in {\sf span} \tilde B_k$ such that $Nx = Nw$.
    - Let $u=w-x$, so $Nu=0$.
  - Let $\tilde A_k$ be the set of vectors obtained above.
  - Let $B_k = \tilde B_k \cup \tilde A_k$. Then $B_k$ is a Jordan basis for $T_{|_{U_k}}$.
  - In the end, $B_0$ is a Jordan basis for $T_{|_G}$.
- Recollecting all Jordan bases for each $T_{|_{G(\lambda,T)}}$ produces a Jordan basis for $T$.

I found this method myself by digging into the proof in Axler's Done Right book. I hope it is correct.

Comment: On the third to the last bullet point, I think you meant $\tilde{A_k}$.

Comment: @SungjinKim Thanks! I edited it just now. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that was it.