# Finding a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=J$ in the Jordan canonical form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, jordan-normal-form

I'm solving two problems that envolved to find a inversible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=J$ is in the Jordan form.

When $A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-2 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
and $A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.

To me it's easy to find the jordan form for this two matrices:

$J=\begin{bmatrix}
i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -i & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -i \\
\end{bmatrix}$
and $J=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & i & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -i \\
\end{bmatrix}$ resp.

But how can I find the matrix $P$ in each case in a easy way and also, I would like to know if there exist a standard form to do it, thanks!

Comment: For your cases, $J$ is diagonal, so finding $P$ is just the normal procedure for diagonalization.

Comment: Regarding a "standard form" to find the Jordan form in general, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2322755/81360).

Comment: If you have a real matrix $A$ and, after Joranizing,  a Jordan block  of size $m$. with $a+bi$ on the  main diagonal and 1's on the super diagonal, you will also have a Jordan block of size $m$ with $a-bi$ on the main diagonal cand 1's on the super-diagonal. Then you can find a real invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ has  a block diagonal  Jordan block with $m$ 2x2 matrices of the form $[a, -b] $in the first row and $[b,a]$ in the second row on the main block diagonal and 2x2 identity matrices  on the block super-diagonal..